# Need to read from a file and add the elements and get avg in python 3.4

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have an input file as following:

```
75647485 10 20 13 12 14 17 13 16
63338495 15 20 11 17 18 20 17 20
00453621  3 10  4 10 20 18 15 10
90812341 18 18 16 20  8 20  7 15
```

I need to find the mean of each row starting from the second element till the end [1:8] and give the output as:

```
ID        Mean     Lowest number       Highest number   
75647485  14.37     10                     20
90812341  ...       ...                    ...
```

I am new to python, so can someone please help. I don't need to write the output to the file, but just displaying it on the console would work.

thank you

Comment: Pls add your starting code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array = [ [int(s) for s in line.split()] for line in open('file') ]
for line in array:
    print('%08i %3.1f %3i %3i' % (line[0], sum(line[1:])/len(line[1:]), min(line[1:]), max(line[1:])))
```

This produces the output:

```
75647485 14.4  10  20
63338495 17.2  11  20
00453621 11.2   3  20
90812341 15.2   7  20
```

#### Alternate Version

To assure that the file handle is properly closed, this version uses `with`.  Also, string formatting is done with the more modern `format` function:

```
with open('file') as f:
    array = [ [int(s) for s in line.split()] for line in f ]
for line in array:
    print('{:08.0f} {:3.1f} {:3.0f} {:3.0f}'.format(line[0], sum(line[1:])/len(line[1:]), min(line[1:]), max(line[1:])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using numpy:

```
import numpy
numpy.mean(mylist[1:8])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fileRecord = namedtuple('RecordID', 'num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8)

import csv
for line in csv.reader(open("file.txt", header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")):
    numList = fileRecord._make(line)
    numListDict = numList._asdict()
    lowest = numListDict[0]
    highest = numListDict[7]
    for (key, value) in numListDict: 
       total += value;
    mean = total/8
    print (lowest, highest, mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using pandas. Much more scalable and many more features. It is also based on numpy.

```
import pandas as pd
x='''75647485 10 20 13 12 14 17 13 16
63338495 15 20 11 17 18 20 17 20
00453621  3 10  4 10 20 18 15 10
90812341 18 18 16 20  8 20  7 15'''
from cStringIO import StringIO # py27
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), delim_whitespace=True, header=None, index_col=0)
print df.T.max()
#75647485    20
#63338495    20
#453621      20
#90812341    20

print df.T.min()
#75647485    10
#63338495    11
#453621       3
#90812341     7

print df.T.mean()
#75647485    14.375
#63338495    17.250
#453621      11.250
#90812341    15.250
```